# How to Log connections

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
How can I log ROS TCP connection creations and destructions?
I'm trying to move all my clients to persistent connections to avoid recreating too many TCP sockets (to avoid they dangle for a couple of minutes), but I still have many TIME_WAIT connections (for which I cannot see to which process they belong with `netstat` nor `lsof -i`)

Maybe enabling logs for roscore?
We have diamondback but we're migrating soon to electric.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27790/how-to-log-connections/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it helps to set the loggerlevel of roscpp or similar to DEBUG.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if it helps, but rosnode info shows all open socket connections. The implementation uses an xmlrpc call that you could maybe also use to poll open connections. Not really nice though...

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1